# Вывести текст, составленный из первых букв всех слов

Tags: python, строки

Помогите,пожалуйста, кому не сложно.

Comment: Тут принято помогать, а не решать за кого-то. Покажите входные данные, ожидаемый результат и вашу попытку (даже если там какая-то фигня)

Comment: Нет, фигню не надо. Должно быть решение, пусть и неправильное - где ошибка, подскажем.

Answer (score 1):

1. разбить текст на слова используя метод `split()`
2. пройтись по всем словам, получая по первой букве `[0]`, и сформировать список первых букв
3. соединить буквы из сформированного списка в строку через метод `''.join()` (с пустым разделителем)

по идее весь алгоритм можно сделать в одну строку

Answer (score 1):

```
print("".join(next(zip(*input().split()))))
```